# How to change the value of a attribute in a class?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code :

`<input class="inp " type="text" value="0.01" inputmode="numeric">`

I want to change the attribute value but nothing i tried worked .
I tried this metrods :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inp")[0].value=0.02;
document.getElementsByClassName("inp")[0].setAttribute("value","0.02");
document.querySelector("input.inp").value=0.02;
```

None of these seem to work they just change the value on the surface or the hud but when i try to use the changed value its always the value before i made the changes.

Am i doing something wrong or the site just restricts the changes of that attribute ?

Comment: I just tried, and each variation/approach does change the element's `value`

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a strong misconception here. Your code works fine, the problem is your expectations when modifying the `value` **attribute**.

The `value` **attribute** (as opposed to the `value` *property*!) serves only a single purpose: Declaratively defining the **initial value** *in the HTML*. **With any Javascript you typically never interact with the `value` *attribute*.**

Changing it later **will not change the displayed value** (but it will change `el.defaultValue`), nor will changing the value by interacting with the element update the attribute.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("input.inp");
console.log(`el.value: ${el.value}, <input value="${el.getAttribute('value')}">, el.defaultValue: ${el.defaultValue}`);

el.value=0.33;
console.log(`el.value: ${el.value}, <input value="${el.getAttribute('value')}">, el.defaultValue: ${el.defaultValue}`);

el.setAttribute("value","0.66");
console.log(`el.value: ${el.value}, <input value="${el.getAttribute('value')}">, el.defaultValue: ${el.defaultValue}`);
```

```html
<input class="inp" type="text" value="0.01">
```

Comment: nicely done.....

Answer (score 1):

After testing your code, it works correctly, your issue seems to be outside of the code.

### All of these work correctly.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("inp1")[0].value=0.02;
document.getElementsByClassName("inp2")[0].setAttribute("value","0.02");
document.querySelector("input.inp3").value=0.02;
```

```html
<input class="inp1" type="text" value="0.01" inputmode="numeric">
<input class="inp2" type="text" value="0.01" inputmode="numeric">
<input class="inp3" type="text" value="0.01" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: If the above answer was proving the correctness of the OP's 3 alternatives, each by an executable SO snippet instead of an outside *fiddle* , it could be the accepted one.

Comment: No, there is some tricky notes about using `setAttribute`! it will only change the element value if no other code set it through the `value` property (as it sets the default/initial value). see the connexo answer or test this more deeply. eg: if you run inp[0].value=0.02; inp[0].setAttribute("value","0.03"); then the final value you see is 0.02 not 0.03 even if it is called later!